# Как написать полуслово с относительным местоимением?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, морфология, диалог, многоточие

Не могу понять, какой из вариантов является правильным при обрыве слова (например, в диалоге). Ниже указал три варианта. Какой из них верный и почему?

Первый
*— Это абракадабра!

— Абра... что?*

Второй
*— Это абракадабра!

— Абра-что?*

Третий
*— Это абракадабра!

— Абрачто?*

Comment: Первый вариант верен.

Comment: Спасибо. Это чисто интуитивное решение или есть какое-то правило?

Comment: Многоточием обозначается заминка в речи (§ 186 Правил-1956: http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/161-mnogo). Второй и третий варианты никак нельзя объяснить с точки зрения правил пунктуации.

Comment: @Nektoid спасибо, стало понятнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В художественном тексте многоточия используются гораздо чаще, чем в нехудожественной литературе. В речи героев многоточие является знаком прерывистого дыхания, затрудненной речи, трудностей с произношением, вспоминанием или пониманием.

> В поисках ошибки Мельхиор задумчиво перебирал чудесные четки, где каждое седьмое зерно было вырезано из золотистого тигрового глаза. Начинаясь солнечным знаком и заканчиваясь гексаграммой, граненые бусины намекали на зашифрованный рецепт «Дела Солнца». Иногда перебор граней складывался в буквенную последовательность, которая отзывалась глухим воспоминанием.
> — Абра… Абрака… — шептал он, стиснув пылающие виски, но ничего не получалось. — Алкоголь, Баня, Роса, Амальгама, Кристалл, Антимоннум, — пытался подобрать подходящее. — Абра… Абракадабра!..
> [Е. Парнов. Мальтийский жезл](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=85916&p=93)

В диалоге, при обрыве непонятого слова, нужно, считаю, использовать первый вариант.

> — Да ерунда, – отмахнулась Ринка. — Стой! Скажи-ка лучше, знаешь ли ты магазин, где продается научная аппаратура?
> **— Научная абра… что?**
> — Штучки для ученых и магов, — перевела Ринка на понятный язык.
> [И. Успенская. Чёрный вдовец](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=623886&p=31)

О [**многоточии**](http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000037/st011.shtml) интересно и доходчиво написано у Н. С. Валгиной.

Answer (score 1):

Первый. Многоточие символизирует недоговорённость, обрыв (слова или фразы).